# Creating an “unzip” custom module in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am creating a website that will allow users to upload projects. Project submissions will consist of .zip file. Once the user uploads their project, I need to unzip the .zip file and find the .html file . Also, it needs to be possible to upload these projects through the web interface "Add New Content" and through Node.create by way of the services module.
note I'm using the PclZip library.
This is part of the code I use when the uploaded file but it does not extract the file

```
function custom_unzip_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
if ($node->type == 'flipper') {
$p_zipname = base_path() .'sites/default/files'.$form_state["complete form"]["#node"]->field_file["und"][0]["filename"];
$to_extract = base_path() . 'test/';
$zip = new PclZip($p_zipname);
$ar = $zip->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $to_extract);
}}
```